# How can I modify this (simple) equation to produce my desired result?

Tags: formula

I have a database of 817 items, each given a "rank" of 1 to 817 (the smaller the number, the "better" the item).  This rank is based off of many factors that indicate quality.

Now, I need to assign a "value" to these items, with the item at rank 1 being valued the most, and the value decreasing with rank (non-linear).

The easiest first attempt was to simply choose an arbitrary base (100,000) and divide by the rank:

```
$value = 100000 / $rank;

/**
 * Rank : Value
 * 1    : 100,000
 * 2    : 50,000
 * 3    : 33,333
 * etc.
 */
```

This produces exponential decay, as shown in the red line in this image:

[image: graph]

However, I wish to value these items in a manner that looks more like the blue line above.  How can I change my formula to achieve this?

Comment: Would a linear fit do? That would be trivial

Comment: `1/x` isn't exponential decay, it's hyberbolic decay, isn't it?

Comment: @Neil probably.  `Math != My Specialty`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `1/sqrt(x)` (i.e, `pow(x, -1/2)`) for starters. If that's still not slow enough, try a smaller fractional power.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you go with linear?

```
value = n - rank
```

where `n` is the count of your items, i.e. 817.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried but use exponent instead of dividing by 1000 of a base 2.

**UPDATES**

```
value = 2 pow (n-rank)
```

Comment: 2^-x actually ends up going to zero faster than 1/x.

Comment: @duskwuff, yeah, that's what I discovered.